# Multiplication of subnormal and normal numbers under IEEE 754

Tags: floating-point

As far as I understand, when doing this operation, we first need to identify the subnormal value, normalise it, adjust the exponent, and then multiply the significands. Wouldn't it be advantageous to just multiply the significands and use a leading-zero counter on the result? It seems like removing some steps could speed things up. And I understand that a leading-zero counter could be expensive, but I have the impression that today there are many fast implementations that could be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above all, hardware floating-point units are optimised for normalised numbers.

Multipliers, and even more dividers, can be a bit simpler if the two inputs are already normalised :

- there is the implicit leading 1 always in the same place.
- rounding as well always occurs on same digits, which can allow some simplifications for bits that will discarded.
- most division algorithms (Newton, SRT, ...) only really work with normalised numbers.

Floating point Adder/subtractors need to re-aling mantissas before doing the  addition/subtraction, even for normalised numbers, sometimes this shifter can be reused for re-normalisation before multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check not only for denormalised numbers but also for zeroes because inf x denormalised = inf, but inf x 0 = NaN. And you can use the usual method for division as well, where it is extra valuable. Much better to use the exact same first part of the hardware, you need to design it only once.

Someone might have tried this and rejected it. Someone might actually be implementing it and tells nobody. You’d have to talk to some engineers at Intel, AMD, Arm, ibm, apple to find out.

But please write down the complete steps to do a fused multiply-add. With no hand waving. Complete. Removing one case at the very start to remove complexity is usually helpful.